# RDLC Report Column Freezing Click Anomaly

Tags: .net, rdlc

I have a RDLC report, and need to freeze the first two columns (when scrolling horizontally, they need to remain in place).  Additionally, I need to freeze the first row in the Tablix (lets call this the header).  I'm able to do this using the Advanced mode to freeze the header row.  Then using the Tablix options, I can freeze the first two columns.

This looks like a solution, however, the first two columns are expandable, and allow a click for drillthrough.  The expand (plus sign), and drillthrough click do not work once you start to scroll horizontally.

Is there another method to freeze the first two columns using the "Advanced mode" that would allow the values in those columns to be clickable?

Thanx in advance!